# Non pretendere altro in avvenire

Tags: phrase-request

Buongiorno,

Volevo sapere qual è il significato di
 "Non pretendere altro in avvenire".

Fa differenza se quest'espressione viene usata in modo informale o per iscritto?

Grazie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essenzialmente il significato è quello letterale cioè rinunciare a qualsiasi ulteriore pretesa futura.

Diciamo che il contesto in cui si trovano clausole di questo tipo è quello legale (o formale) e solitamente ci si riferisce ad esse come ***[clausole di stile](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausola_di_stile)***.

Difficilmente useresti questa espressione nei discorsi informali di tutti i giorni.

Le puoi trovare nei contratti, negli atti notarili e, in generale in quasi tutte quelle situazioni in cui una delle controparti intende liberarsi definitivamente da un obbligo nei confronti dell'altra.

> Sono clausole di stile solo quelle espressioni generiche frequentemente contenute nei contratti o negli atti notarili, che per la loro eccessiva ampiezza e indeterminazione rivelano la funzione di semplice completamento formale.

Puoi trovare [qui](http://www.altalex.com/documents/massimario/2011/10/25/clausole-di-stile-rinuncia-precisa-e-circostanziata-esclusione) alcuni riferimenti.